# Insufficient privileges when GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_ALERT

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I'm installing new Oracle [12.1.0.2 in docker](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/dockerfiles/12.1.0.2). After installation I just want to execute few of prepared (not by me) scripts.

One of them on which execution is failing is

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_ALERT to TESTUSR;
```

`ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`

I'm executing scripts with SYSTEM user from SQLDeveloper. Can somebody tell me what do I need to do to be able to execute this script?

Comment: Login as `SYSDBA` and run the script.

Comment: you may need to connect as sysbda. You have that privilege? Try connecting like this: conn / as sysdba, . If the connection is successful , try the grant statement.

Comment: connecting as sysdba was the trick. I was connecting just like SYSTEM user without sysdba.

Answer (score 1):

**Admin Privileges or the `EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE` Role Required to Execute DBMS_ALERTS**

Per the documentation here, https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG99875 (section "User Access to Objects in the SYS Schema")

It states:
*Users with explicit object privileges or those who connect with administrative privileges (SYSDBA) can access objects in the SYS schema.*

**Since you are using the `system` account, you could execute the package, `DBMS_ALERTS`, logging in as `system@db as sysdba`. See below screenshot to see how to add the `dbs` role or `sysdba` privilege**

---

Alternatively, you could use the `EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE` to execute `DBMS_ALERTS`.

You can see user or roles whom have this access here:

```
usr@db>SELECT
  2      grantee,
  3      granted_role,
  4      default_role
  5  FROM
  6      dba_role_privs
  7  WHERE
  8      1 = 1
  9      AND   grantee IN (
 10          'DBA',
 11          'SYS',
 12          'SYSTEM'
 13      )
 14          AND   granted_role IN (
 15          'DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE',
 16          'EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE',
 17          'SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE'
 18      )
 19  ORDER BY
 20      1,
 21      2;
GRANTEE   GRANTED_ROLE           DEFAULT_ROLE
DBA       DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE    YES
DBA       EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE   YES
DBA       SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE    YES
SYS       DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE    YES
SYS       EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE   YES
SYS       SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE    YES


6 rows selected.

usr@db>SELECT
  2      grantee,
  3      granted_role
  4  FROM
  5      dba_role_privs
  6  WHERE
  7      1 = 1
  8      AND   granted_role = 'DBA'
  9  ORDER BY
 10      1,
 11*     2;
usr@db>/
GRANTEE   GRANTED_ROLE
SYS       DBA
SYSTEM    DBA
```

It is bad practice to use the `sys` account even though it has adequate privileges.

The best solution is to grant the `dba` role to a user account, eg `usr`.

Using the `sysdba` privilege (e.g. `system@db as sysdba`), create a user having the needed privileges:

```
create user usr identified by Pa$$W0rD;
grant create session to usr;
grant dba to usr;
```

Consequently, you could log in with the `dba` role to execute this package.

In SQL*Plus, this would look like this (assumes `usr` has been granted the `dba` role):

```
usr@db as dba
```

In SQL Developer, you would set-up your connection as seen below, selecting the role, `dba`:
 [image]